# Convert image to thumbnail and save it

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, file, thumbnails

I have a file input in asp.net. I want to get the image, display the thumbnail, and save it. Here is the aspx...

```
form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
    <input type="file" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_upload" OnClick="btn_upload_Click" Text="Upload" />
    <br />
    <asp:Image ID="image_placeholder" runat="server" Visible="false" />
</div>
</form>
```

And here is the c# code behind. I can get the image to display, I just have difficulty saving it.

```
var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
            string fileName = postedFile.FileName;

            if (fileName != "")
            {
                Stream fs = postedFile.InputStream;

                System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);

                using (System.Drawing.Image thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        thumbnail.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                        Byte[] bytes2 = new Byte[memoryStream.Length];
                        memoryStream.Position = 0;
                        memoryStream.Read(bytes2, 0, (int)bytes2.Length);
                        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes2, 0, bytes2.Length);
                        image_placeholder.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
                        image_placeholder.Visible = true;
                        var desktopFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
                        thumbnail.Save(desktopFolder, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    }
                }
```

The error I get is "A generic error ocurred in GDI+" 
I take it this is because I'm calling two `thumbnail.Save`

Anyways, the image displays fine, it is just problematic when it comes to actually saving it.

Comment: Possibly a rights issue, your iis server account needs the rights to save the file.

Comment: Right now i'm just running it off of my local dev environment, trying to save it to my desktop

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to write a small application to generate thumbnail images from PDF files. I ended up using a library based on ImageMagick called Magick.NET.This library made it very easy to do what you're describing. I used the method `MagickImage.Resize()` to resize the image to thumbnail size, the property `MagickImage.Format` to set the thumbnail's image format, and the method `MagickImage.Write()` to write the thumbnail to disk. You might want to check it out at https://magick.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 3rd party library here [http://imageresizer.codeplex.com/.](http://imageresizer.codeplex.com/) I struggled with the uploading of images and retaining quality, this library helped me out alot.

In your view:

```
@model YourProject.ViewModels.ProductImageUploadCreateViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "ProductImage", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
     <input type="file" name="ImageFile1" id="ImageFile1">
}
```

Your controller:

public class ProductImageController : Controller
{
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Upload(ProductImageUploadCreateViewModel viewModel)
     {
          if (!ModelState.IsValid)
          {
               return View(viewModel);
          }

```
      if (viewModel.ImageFile1 != null)
      {
           UploadImage(viewModel.ProductId, "1", viewModel.ImageFile1);
      }

      // Return to where ever...
 }
```

}
Your upload method:

private void UploadImage(int productId, string imageNo, HttpPostedFileBase imageFile)
{
     string uploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/Assets/Images/Products/" + productId);
     if (!Directory.Exists(uploadPath))
     {
          Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadPath);
     }

```
 Dictionary<string, string> versions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 versions.Add("_m", "width=150&height=150&scale=both&format=jpg");  // Medium size

 string filePrefix = productId + "_" + imageNo;
 versions.Add("_s", "width=90&height=90&scale=both&format=jpg");  // Small size
 versions.Add("_l", "width=300&height=300&scale=both&format=jpg");  // Large size

 foreach (string fileSuffix in versions.Keys)
 {
      // Generate a filename
      string fileName = Path.Combine(uploadPath, filePrefix + fileSuffix);

      // Let the image builder add the correct extension based on the output file type
      fileName = ImageBuilder.Current.Build(imageFile, fileName, new ResizeSettings(versions[fileSuffix]), false, true);
 }
```

}
Have a look on their website, there are a couple of samples that you can work through. I hope this helps :)